# C++ Why do reference values change previous values?

Tags: c++, reference, cout, ref

Can somebody help me wrap my head around this? I thought the output would be 20 10 20 (in order that is ref1, num1, num2). Why does it output 20 20 20? ref1 changing also changes num1? Reference values are a new concept for me so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I know you guys much prefer pointer values but in class this is what we're learning about so I want to get it down. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 20;
int &ref1 = num1;

ref1 = num2;

std::cout << "Ref1: " << ref1 << std::endl
          << "Num1: " << num1 << std::endl
          << "Num2: " << num2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Also how do I find out their memory values/addresses? That's something that's totally throwing me off too. I suppose I might want to make a separate question for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it output 20 20 20

*ref1* is a reference to *num1*, so when you assign *ref1* with *num2* in fact you assign *num1* to *num2*, this is the goal of the references

so it is like if you do

```
int * ref1 = &num1;

*ref1 = num2;
```

> how do I find out their memory values/addresses

*ref1* on the right side (the case in the *printf*) gives the value of *num1*, to have the address of the referenced element rather than its value as usual use *&*, so *&ref1* values *&num1*. Note you cannot reassign a reference, you can only initialize them

Comment: It's that easy wow! I thought I must be missing some step. I guess I'm just trying to overcomplicate an easy concept. Thanks Bruno!

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting used to stack overflow. That's helpful I should probably go and do that to my old questions too.

Comment: maybe worth mentioning that `&ref1` is the adress of `num1`

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes you are right, I edited my answer, thank you

Comment: @bruno What do you mean by you cannot reassign a reference? Isn't that exactly what we just did?

Comment: @SalvGi I mean after *ref1 = num2* nothing change on the fact *ref1* is still a reference to *num1*, not to *num2*. Perhaps my sentence if not clear, do you think it is better to remove it ?

Comment: @bruno No, it makes sense now that you said that part! I'm just trying to keep up and don't want to make mistakes. You've been a great help!

Answer (score 2):

you can understand it as **reference variable  is alias**, i.e just another name for existing variable
thus ref1 another name of num1
when you do ref1=num2 , ref1 is assigned with  num2 value i.e 20 and similary num1 get assign with 20 value